# How can I join together values in submit text box into a url API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

[image]

I'm working on a project where you ask the National Parks API for info of parks based on the state abbreviation you enter, as in OR(Oregon) or WA (Washington), etc. I understand how to write it for one value, using template literals, but if I search for more than one state at a time, that when writing the code gets tricky.  Im looking to get it to send a call to the api like this:
https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?stateCode=or%2Cwa

I would be putting "or,wa" into my search  box

(Documentation for National Parks API endpoint I'm using:
https://www.nps.gov/subjects/developer/api-documentation.htm#/parks/getPark)

JS:

```
'use strict'

$(watchForm());

function watchForm(){
    $('form').submit(event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        getParkInfo();
    })
}

function getParkInfo(){
    var searchBox = $('.inputBox').val();
    var numResults = $('.numPerPage').val();

    const url = *** How do I write this???***


    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            displayResults(response);
        })
}

function displayResults(response){
    $('#results-list').empty();
    for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
        $('#results-list').append(
            `<li>
            <a href="${response.data[i].url}"><h3>${response.data[i].fullName}</h3></a>
            <p>${response.data[i].description}</p>
            <p>${response.data[i].addresses[i]}</p>
            <a href="${response.data[i].directionsUrl}"<p>Address</p></a>
            </li>`
        )
    }
    $('#results').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Search Your Favorite National Parks</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>NPS Search Up</h1>
            <form>
                <input class="inputBox" type="text"  required> Search for Park
                <br><br>
                <input class="numPerPage" type="text" value="10" required> Results per page
                <br><br>
                <input class="submitBox" type="submit">
            </form>

            <section id="results" class="hidden">
                <h2>Search Results</h2>
                <ul id="results-list">
                </ul>
            </section>  
        </div>

        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `URL` instance with your base url.

```
var url = new URL("https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks");
```

and then add your query parameters to this `URL` instance like this

```
url.searchParams.append('stateCode', searchBox)
url.searchParams.append('limit', numResults);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var joinedSearchEntry = searchBox.split(',').join('%2C')
var url = `https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?stateCode=${joinedSearchEntry}`
```

or save a line

```
var url = `https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?stateCode=${searchBox.split(',').join('%2C')}`
```

Let me know if I'm missing something but this should be fine.